# Is there a way to collect the data and inspect in one pass using groupby function

Tags: sql, group-by, hql, partitioning, windowing

[Sample Data of table_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB7pg.png)

Have this Query that returns
select
customer,
SUM(CASE WHEN activity IN ( 'a','b')
THEN  1
ELSE  0 END)  AS num_activity_a_or_b
from table_1
group by customer

Results:
[image: Results]
[image: Updated results]

Want to extend this to return one more column if for a given code say X1 if the Activity is "a" and "c" then return num_of_a_and_c_activity.

A bit stuck how to collect and inpect the code and activities in one pass.
can we combine windowing function to achieve this.

Please advise and help

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN activity IN ( 'a','b') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_activity_a_or_b` should give more than 2 for customer1; actually 4 as there are 1 a and 3 b activities?

Comment: Yes Dhruv Keep eye. your observation is correct The results should be 4 for the num_activity_a_or_b 
But my question is more about the way to solve "Want to extend this to return one more column if for a given code say X1 if the Activity is "a" and "c" then return num_of_a_and_c_activity." >>>Any thoughts on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:
based on the updated results, maybe the below query is what you need
So what i assume is that you need both a and c as well x1 .
So I count distinct activities which are a and c and then do integer division by 2. if only a is present then count distinct =1 but 1/2 =0 in integer division.
It is only 1 when both a and c are present.

```
select 
 customer, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN activity IN ( 'a','b') 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END) AS num_activity_a_or_b,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN code IN ('x1') AND activity IN ( 'a','c') 
     THEN activity 
      ELSE NULL 
   END)/2 AS num_activity_a_and_c
from table_1 
group by customer
```

Maybe your query can be

```
select 
 customer, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN activity IN ( 'a','b') 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END) AS num_activity_a_or_b,
   SUM(CASE WHEN code IN ('x1') AND activity IN ( 'a','c') 
     THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
   END) AS num_activity_a_or_c
from table_1 
group by customer
```

Comment: Hi Dhruv,
This is a bit off as it does the or giving false counts, Looking for (Code=X1 + Activity "A" and "C") , so might need to make an extra pass to count them join back to this dataset.. 
Want in the metric num_activity_a_and_c 
 Was seeing if we could do this in Just one pass...

Comment: based on your input can you add to the table in your question what data should be in the new column

Comment: The results should like this
Customer num_activity_a_or_b num_of_a_and_c_activity
1                             4                             1
2                             1                                 0

Comment: @RBon, you need to give better sample data if you've got something more complicated in mind.

Comment: @RBon I've posted an updated query. please check.